# How to add feature image url in my template file and content as well?

Tags: php, pages

I am making a template page name new_template.php,here i want to add a feature image source.
how to add featured image source on this blank page. and when i add featured image then the description content is not displaying.
thanks

Comment: Show us your code - what have you done already?

Answer (score 0):

Page's don't by default have a "Featured Image".  If you've found a plugin to do that, then to output the Featured Image use the following function:

```
the_post_thumbnail()
```

You can read more about it in the WordPress Codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

There are various other functions that will return the image markup (`get_the_post_thumbnail ()`), or just the Featured Image source (`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`).  Again, look in the Codex for detailed instructions on how to use these functions.

Comment: okey .. if i have to display content as well then what code need to write ..thanks for your reply

Comment: ohh cool .. its working fine...
the_post_thumbnail() helps me to display the feature image.
thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an untested function that will allow you to paste this code in The Loop or actually get the source of a post thumbnail via get_the_ID. You could also tweak it for custom sizes. Just paste this in your functions.php

```
<?php

function get_featured_image_src($ID){
    if($ID){
        $FI = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($ID), 'full' );
    } else {
        $FI = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
    }
    return $FI[0];
}

?>
```

Then echo it.

```
<?php echo get_featured_image_src(); /* OR get_featured_image_src( get_the_ID() ); when not in loop */ ?>
```